# Linear Algebra, Hoffman and Kunze, Chapter 3, Section 1, Exercise 8.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Describe explicitly a linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^3$ into $\mathbb{R}^3$ which has its range the subspace spanned by $\alpha_1=(1,0,-1)$ and $\alpha_2(1,2,2)$.

Thoughts: As the vectors span the subspace, then they span the vector $v=(a,b,c)\!\in\! W$. I created a $3\times3$ matrix such that $A=[\alpha_1,\alpha_2,v]$. The result were

$x_1=b-c$

$x_2=\dfrac{c+a}{3}$

$x_3\!\in\!\mathbb{R}$

and that $\dfrac{4a+2c}{3}=b$.

Therefore $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ span vectors in this form represented by $e_1$ and $e_2$. Then the linear transformation I created was $T(a,b,c)=(a,\dfrac{4a+2c}{3},c)$, but I'm not confident with that response.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the linear map $f\colon\mathbb R^3\longrightarrow\mathbb R^3$ such that $f(1,0,0)=\alpha_1$, $f(0,1,0)=\alpha_2$ and that $f(0,0,1)=0$, for instance. In other words, take $f(x,y,z)=(x+y,2y,2y-x)$.

Comment: An easy way to do it.  The matrix would be $\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0\\0&2&0\\-1&2&0\end{pmatrix}$.